# ext js infoBubble is not defined

Tags: extjs, google-maps-api-3, infobubble

I am using Ext Js for creating a map markers with infoBubble displayed on click. when i tried to add this code i got the following error : Uncaught ReferenceError: infoBubble is not defined

```
infoBubble = new InfoBubble({
                    content: '<div class="example">Some label</div>',
                    shadowStyle: 1,
                    padding: 10,
                    borderRadius: 5,
                    minWidth: 200,
                    borderWidth:1,
                    disableAutoPan: true,
                    hideCloseButton: false,         
                    backgroundClassName: 'example',

                          });
```

what could be the problem ? 
Any help will be apreciated, thanks

Comment: fixed it with adding : <script type='text/javascript' src="http://www.msg360.co.uk/emails/sample/Scripts/infobubble-compiled.js"></script> to my page.

Answer (score 0):

Try google.maps.InfoBubble instead of InfoBubble and i also see a "," after the last attribute that must be removed